# Угол под 45 градусов у div

Tags: html, css, css3, internet-explorer, clip-path

Друзья, может кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей...
Необходимо у div срезать углы (верхний-левый и нижний правый), под углом 45 градусов.

реализовал через clip-path

```
    .corner45top {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% -200%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(5% -200%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: url("#swipe__clip-path");
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(86,86,86,0.25);
}

.corner45bottom {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 -100%, 100% 0%, 98% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 -100%, 100% 0%, 98% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: url("#swipe__clip-path-bottom");
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(86,86,86,0.25);
}

<svg class="clip-svg">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="swipe__clip-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon points="0.05 -2, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1,0 1,0 1" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs> 
</svg>
   <svg class="clip-svg">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="swipe__clip-path-bottom" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <polygon points="0 -1, 1 0, 0.98 1, 0 1,0 1,0 1" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs> 
</svg>
```

Но все эти "красивости" никак не работают в браузере EDGE, есть ли какой-то простой вариант вылечить это?
Мог бы сделать углы например картинкой, но за блоками есть background-image цветной(

Comment: Это нужно чисто для фона? Может тогда градиент использовать под 45 градусов?

Comment: Нужно для div-ов некоторых, для области контента, футера и некоторых блоков + изображений (вот ссылка на тестовый проект http://artcoupe.myihor.ru/ )

Comment: Можно для Эджа использовать дополнительные стили с использованием border. Пример самих скошенных углов https://codepen.io/timharbour/pen/ECslv

Comment: Дело в том, что основная проблема с блоками контент и футером - им нужны углы с прозрачным фоном и тенью задней(  С обрезкой изображений или блоков на белом/сером/зеленом фоне проблем особенно нет

Comment: На крайний случай - можно для ИЕ скормить картинки с тенью. Если тень не изменяется на ховер.

Comment: Сейчас попробую что-то сотворить, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нам на помощь приходит SVG , подходит такой вариант ?

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 300 300' width="200px" height="200px"> 
  <polygon points="0,100 100,0 300,0 300,200 200,300 0,300" style="fill:yellow; stroke:none; stroke-width:none;"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Делаем маску с помощью `overflow:hidden`. Угол получаем поворотом элемента на 45 градусов  `transform:rotate(-45deg)` (внутренний элемент вертим обратно, чтобы был ровно). С помощью отступов `margin` регулируем глубину среза.

```css
.container{
   transform:rotate(-45deg);
   overflow:hidden;
   height: 160px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.inside{
   transform:rotate(45deg);
   background:#090;
   height:100px;
   width:200px;
   margin:30px auto;
   
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
<div class=inside>Тестовый блок</div>
</div>
```

Comment: только текст не видно :))

Comment: @Geyan Это специально сделано, чтобы показать, что объект обрезается так-же как и с `clip-path`

Comment: дааа ! жесть какая то